# Ruby: What's the use case for Object#send with a static method symbol?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the first chapter of "Ruby Best Practices", and was wondering about this part of a code listing:

```
def text_at(*args) # inside class BlogTest
  args.inject(@feed) { |s,r| s.send(:at, r) }.inner_text
end
```

`@feed` is an instance of `Nokogiri::XML::Node` (representing a XML document), and the method is used to retrieve text from a node like this:

```
self.text_at('rss', 'title')
# same as @feed.at('rss').at('title').inner_text
```

So far, so good. But why does `text_at()` use `Object#send`? What is the difference between...

```
s.send(:at, r) # option 1
s.at(r)        # option 2
```

...that requires using the more obscure first variant in this case?

Comment: `Nokogiri::XML` is module not a class, therefore `@feed` can't be an instance of it, maybe you meant `Nokogiri::XML::Node` (or one of its subclasses)?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/d/deltacloud-client-1.1.3/Nokogiri/XML/Element.html

Comment: toro2k: Probably; I didn't check the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a method is private, it cannot be called as via your option 2 format, and has to be called via your option 1 format.

Note. This is a general answer for what you asked. It may not be relevant for the particular `at` method.

Comment: That is probably it. I was not aware yet that Ruby supports private instance methods.